# Interrupt thread from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I have a class with method (which run threads):

```
public void execute() {
    List<Task> task = read();
    for (Task task: tasks) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have some task class with method like this:

```
public void run() {
    Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
}
```

How can I set interrupt to main class from task class?

Comment: Pass a reference to main thread into the task thread, then just call `Thread.interrupt()` on that reference.

Comment: @AndyTurner it's not good idea, tasks are created in another place. Do you know another solution?

Comment: Will recommend you look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html and associated classes.  Many problems are avoidable by using these newer kinds of classes to deal with this kind of nitty-gritty.

Comment: this run method's interrupt call will throw an InterruptedException, which will be caught by main thread's catch block. Now if you want to Interrupt main thread as well, Call `Thread.currentThread.interrupt();` inside catch block.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava not thread-safe

Answer (score 0):

I hope I could understand your case right, this might help. try it.

```
    try {
        thread.join();
        if(thread.isInterupted()){break;/*?!*/}
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        break;
    }
```

---

Or

```
/*public static */volatile boolean work=true;
public void execute() {
    List<Task> task = read();
    for (Task task: tasks) {
        if(!work){break;}
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
...
public void run() {
    Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
    work=false;
}
```